# Predict probability distribution rather than point estimate from R linear and poisson models

Tags: r, probability, prediction

I'm trying to predict a probability distribution (or parts of the distribution, for example, the inner 95%) from a linear and poisson model in R. Currently, all that I get from the prediction is a point estimate, and I can of course generate the standard errors as well. Is there a way to generate a distribution for the prediction,  aside from perhaps running a Bayesian analysis and generating the posterior distribution?

To give a simple example, I'll use the Batting table from the Lahman baseball database and predict Runs from Hits. I'll do a linear model and a poisson model (not that the poisson distribution is the best for this data, but it will just serve as an example).

```
library(Lahman)
library(tidyverse)

df <- Batting
df <- df %>% filter(yearID > 2009, AB > 200)


## linear model

fit_lm <- lm(R ~ H, data = df)
summary(fit_lm)

predict(fit_lm, newdata = list(H = 50))

## poisson model

fit_pois <- glm(R ~ H, data = df, family = "poisson")
summary(fit_pois)

predict(fit_pois, newdata = list(H = 50), type = "response")
```

Could I potentially just use the predicted `$fit` and the `$se` to generate the distribution?

```
predict(fit_lm, newdata = list(H = 50), se = T)
hist(rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 50, sd = 2*0.34))
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you could probably do this by simulation; 1) draw n mvrnorm samples from the model coefficients / covariance, 2) multiple each of these by each row of the data/newdata to get the mean, 3) pass this mean to rpois, where mean == lambda

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to work back to Monte Carlo simulation. One option would be to estimate a Bayesian model to start and then use one of the canned functions for MCMC simulation off of it. See, for example, the [`merTools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/merTools/index.html) package.